# Is there a way to preserve the order of tests in TestNG without a TestSuite.xml file?

Tags: selenium, testng

I'm doing Selenium tests in TestNG.  I would like to not have the maintenance annoyance of keeping all of my test methods in a separate file and would rather just include a package to scan for @Tests.

Given this scenario, is there a way to preserve the order of the test methods within the test file AND have TestNG consume one test class at a time.  Currently, I am maintaining the method order within the tests with @Test(dependsOn={}) which works; however, I'm seeing this situation

TestClassA

- test_method_1
- test_method_2
- test_method_3
- test_method_4

TestClassB

- test_method_1
- test_method_2
- test_method_3
- test_method_4

Run tests and the order is something like:

- ClassB, method 1
- ClassA, method 1
- ClassB, method 2
- ClassB, method 3
- ClassA, method 2
- ClassA, method 3
- ClassB, method 4
- ClassA, method 4

I don't care about the Class order, I only care that the methods of one Test Class are run entirely before moving on to the next Test Class.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

It would be great to see your testng.xml file. It seems that similar situation is described here: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-xml. I think in your case you should have

```
<class name="TestClassA">
  <methods>
    <include name="test_method_1" />
    <include name="test_method_2" />
    ...
  </methods>
</class>

<class name="TestClassB">
  <methods>
    <include name="test_method_1" />
    <include name="test_method_2" />
    ...
  </methods>
```

Comment: That's the thing though, I want to do it without a testng.xml file - just with package scanning.  In the end, I ended up doing my own class scanning and dynamically creating a testng.xml file which preserves the order and completion of test classes while allowing the tests themselves to be unordered by design.